# TeXstudio: "Recursive" autocomplete for custom commands

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I added this command to reference sections (figures, chapters, etc.):

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
```

Now TeXstudio autocomplete shows me

[image]

but I am missing the autocompletion for the actual sections. Like in the autocomplete for `\ref{...`. Is this possible?

A not so nice solution would bt to skip the `\ref` command

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~#1}
```

and then go for example `\secref{\ref{sec:setup}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would rather use `cleveref`. This will automatically insert the appropriate names of the referenced labels as well as supported by texstudios auto-complete.

For example in the following document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\label{sec:test}

\begin{figure}
\caption{bla}\label{fig:bla}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:bla} \cref{sec:test}

\end{document}
```

Texstudio will prompt

[image]

and the output will be

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This does not answer the question, as stated in the comments. In this answer, I explain how to add macros in texstudio, so that the cursor jumps to a specific location in that macro. A wholly different matter, indeed.**

---

### Original answer

Although I agree with samcarter, for the sake of completeness, there is a way to do the thing you originally wanted in texstudio.

Go to [Macros > Edit macros ...] Then create a new macro, give it a name, an abbreviation (not required and quite useless imho) and a trigger (good design is important for the triggers). In the code section, you would add

```
 \secref{%|section%|}
```

Save and close. In your editor window, type the trigger and the trigger text will automatically be replaced by the macro code `\secref{section}` with the focus of the curser select the word `section` in the braces, ready to be edited.

[image]

As you can see, I abuse of this function. (There's a lot of crap in the picture, as I was testing what was useful to me and I haven't cleaned up the mess, yet.)

---

btw, I use a space at the beginning and at the end of most of my triggers to prevent texstudio to convert "normal text" to some macro. E. g. the macro `ml` without the spaces would be really annoying, as any word containing the sequence 'ml' would get a macro right in the middle of it! If I was typing Umlaut without looking, I would get `U\SI{aut and the rest of the text in the braces,}{\ml}` which doesn't make sense at all. You can do much more with the triggers and the macros, just click on the `?` next to the word "Trigger" and try for yourself.

Comment: Are you sure this would make the labels for the sections appear in the autocomplete box? If not, this does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I misunderstood the question, as I now realize! It zeemz zomewon wass standing on ze leadership *readwithastrongGermanaccent*

Comment: Ok, no worries. I would suggest you delete the 'answer', however, lest someone else gets confused by this.

Comment: Interresting anyway, did not knew that!